# git worktree update remote branch

Tags: git

I have a remote branch that I checked out in a worktree with

`git worktree add ../test dummyRemoteBranch`

I want to know if the `dummyRemoteBranch` is updated, how do I do a git pull so that the worktree has the most updated code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd ../test
git pull origin dummyRemoteBranch
```

If you want to sync with some other branch, replace `dummyRemoteBranch` with it.